# Navigation and text for li item

Tags: html, css, image, navigation, navbar

I am currently trying to create a navigation bar where I have an medium sized image on top of the <li> tag with text underneath (similar to css-tricks).
I have tried background-image and also an img within li tag itself and still no joy.

My main goal is so that the user can click the icon and/or the text and it will still direct them to the correct page.

If you have any additional questions I am more than happy to assist.

```css
nav#navBar img {
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

nav#navBar {
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 0 black;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

nav#navBar * {
    display: inline;
    padding: 15px;
}

nav#navBar li {padding: 30px;}
nav#navBar li.blue:hover {border-bottom: 2px solid #33A1DE;}
nav#navBar li.red:hover {border-bottom: 2px solid #CC3232;}
nav#navBar li.green:hover {border-bottom: 2px solid #28AE7B;}
nav#navBar li.purple:hover {border-bottom: 2px solid #7A378B;}

nav#navBar li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
  <nav id="navBar">
    <img src="#">
    <ul>
      <li class="green"><a href="#home">ARTICLES</a></li>
      <li class="blue"><a href="#">SNIPPETS</a></li>
      <li class="red"><a href="#">MEMBERS</a></li>
      <li class="purple"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put a background image on the li tag and use padding to push the text down.

```
nav#navBar li.green {background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat; padding-top: 30px;}
```

Comment: Hey sandman, thanks for the input. I have tried your suggestion and didn't mean to get the outcome, could I be doing something wrong? I copy and pasted your code straight into mine.

Comment: Hey sandman, that works a charm! How would I resize the image, as nav#navBar li a img doesn't work, thanks.